# What is the quickest way to obtain elven chainmail for my fighter/mage main and bard companion in Baldur's Gate II: SoA?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

I'm playing Baldur's Gate II: SoA (Enhanced Edition) with a main character that is a fighter/mage with a bard companion, both of which can cast wizard spells. What is the fastest way to obtain armor (elven chainmail) for both of them? I haven't played this game is years, so I don't recall where to obtain these items.

I found a list of this item from a wiki:

https://baldursgate.fandom.com/wiki/Elven_Chain_Mail#Shadows_of_Amn

However, I'm not familiar with these areas and I don't know which of them are unlocked or not depending on the chapter.

Is there any elven chainmail that I can pursue early to close the armor gap on these characters?

Comment: Why use chainmail if there are better bracers, or robes?

Comment: Bards cannot wear robes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get both as early as chapter 2.

Head to the playhouse in the Five Flagons in in the Bridge District. Head to the basement and watch the play. This will begin the quest Free Haer'Dalis from Imprisonment by Mekrath.

Make sure you have a free space in the party so you can briefly recruit Haer'Dalis. He is wearing Elven Chain- this can be removed and worn by another party member so equip it to the protagonist.

Continue the quest. At a later point you will encounter an enemy wearing [Melodic Chain](https://baldursgate.fandom.com/wiki/Melodic_Chain?so=search)- +3 Elven Chain that can only be worn by bards. You can equip this one to your bard (usually I give it to Haer'Dalis to make up for stealing his for Imoen).

Alternatively, you can use the Console to "buy" it (whether you consider this cheating is up to you- it's a single player game).

```
C:CreateItem("CHAN12")    
C:AddGold(-5000)
```

The first command spawns elven chain. The second command subtracts its value from your gold (optional of course).